# Using Raphael.js is it possible to position an element relatively and then offset it by an absolute unit?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have an issue where I have to produce a fluid visualisation but while keeping certain aspects of the design with fixed units. E.g. I have a horizontal bar drawn with a label inside and aligned to the right. I want to position the label exactly 10px from the right hand side of the 38% width rect. Is this possible? I've tried all sorts and can't seem to figure out a nice way of doing it...

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! So i'm still positioning the label with relative units and then im using a Raphael transform to offset it with absolute units. E.g.

```
todayLabel = paper.text(
     (i * filters.timelineDayWidth) + '%', // x
     24, // y
     'Today ' + today.getUTCDate() + ' ' +today.getMonthNameShort()
);

todayLabel.attr({
    'text-anchor': 'end'
});

todayLabel.transform('t-10,0');
```